# setState to nested object delete value

Tags: reactjs

I have the following state:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    title: "",
    exchangeTypes: [],
    errors: {
        title: "",
        exchangeTypes: "",
      }
})
```

I am using a form validation in order to populate the `state.errors` object if a condition is not respected.

```
function formValidation(e){
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let errors = state.errors;

    switch (true) {
      case (name==='title' && value.length < 4): 
        setState(prevState => ({
            errors: {                            // object that we want to update
                ...prevState.errors,             // keep all other key-value pairs
                [name]: 'Title cannot be empty' // update the value of specific key
            }
        }))
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  }
```

When I do so, the object DOES update BUT it deletes the value that I have not updated.

**Before I call formValidation**
My `console.log(state)` is:

```
{
    "title": "",
    "exchangeTypes: [],
    "errors": {
            title: "",
            exchangeTypes: "",
    }
}
```

**After I call formValidation**
My `console.log(state)` is:

```
{
    "errors": {
            title: "Title cannot be empty",
            exchangeTypes: ""
        }
}
```

**SO** my other `state` values have disappeared. There is only the `errors` object.

I followed this guide: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

What I want:

```
{
    "title": "",
    "exchangeTypes: [],
    "errors": {
            title: "Title cannot be empty",
            exchangeTypes: "",
    }
}
```

What I get:

```
   {
        "errors": {
                title: "Title cannot be empty",
                exchangeTypes: "",
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unlike the setState in class component, setState via useState doesn't automatically merge when you use an object as the value. You have to do it manually

```js
setState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState, // <- here
  errors: {
    // object that we want to update
    ...prevState.errors, // keep all other key-value pairs
    [name]: 'Title cannot be empty', // update the value of specific key
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Though you can certainly use the `useState` hook the way you're doing, the more common convention is to track the individual parts of your component's state separately. This is because `useState` replaces state rather than merging it, as you've discovered.

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html):

> You don’t have to use many state variables. State variables can hold objects and arrays just fine, so you can still group related data together. However, unlike this.setState in a class, updating a state variable always replaces it instead of merging it.

So in practice, your code might look like the following:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const [exchangeTypes, setExchangeTypes] = useState([]);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({
    title: "",
    exchangeTypes: "",
  });

  function formValidation(e) {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    switch (true) {
      case (name === 'title' && value.length < 4): 
        setErrors({
          ...errors,
          [name]: 'Title cannot be empty'
        });
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```